# Is it possible to identify multiple fingers in fingerprints API of Android?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

And can we perform different functionality on those?
I need to use those API for my project and confused as what if API consider all fingerprints same. And how the different fingerprints can be saved and used for different operations?
Have searched the API and found these.

These lines in that API means?

```
   public static class AuthenticationResult {
    private Fingerprint mFingerprint;
    private CryptoObject mCryptoObject;
    /**
     * Authentication result
     *
     * @param crypto the crypto object
     * @param fingerprint the recognized fingerprint data, if allowed.
     * @hide
     */
    public AuthenticationResult(CryptoObject crypto, Fingerprint fingerprint) {
        mCryptoObject = crypto;
        mFingerprint = fingerprint;
    }
    /**
     * Obtain the crypto object associated with this transaction
     * @return crypto object provided to {@link FingerprintManager#authenticate(CryptoObject,
     *     CancellationSignal, int, AuthenticationCallback, Handler)}.
     */
    public CryptoObject getCryptoObject() { return mCryptoObject; }
    /**
     * Obtain the Fingerprint associated with this operation. Applications are strongly
     * discouraged from associating specific fingers with specific applications or operations.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    public Fingerprint getFingerprint() { return mFingerprint; }
};
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.java#258

Comment: I believe the user has to register a fingerprint with the device first (ex. lock screen), and the api only allows for authentication of the already registered fingerprint

Answer (score 1):

With stock Android, currently all Fingerprints are considered equal.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues/20

As **mariotaku** says at the bottom there is a way with the hidden API to tell Fingerprints apart. But this could likely break in future releases.

> `/**
>    * Obtain the Fingerprint associated with this operation. Applications are strongly
>    * discouraged from associating specific fingers with specific applications or operations.
>    *
>    * @hide
>    */
>   public Fingerprint getFingerprint() { return mFingerprint; }`

Not the `@hide` in the code block. Meaning this function is not available *publicly* so you would have to use reflection to access it.

### Side note:

According to this link, there is the ability to use different fingerprint gestures to launch different apps on newer Huawei phones.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/42p8ba/different_fingerprint_launches_different_app/

Upon further inspection, this is actually nothing to do with reading different fingerprints but rather using gestures on the fingerprint sensor to perform different actions. These gestures can be performed with any finger, not only the ones registered as authentication fingerprints.
http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-fingerprint-gestures-honor-6x